# Can I interrupt the process of rendering and resume it later?

Tags: rendering

Let's say I have a huge project with a rendering time of 1000 hours or more.
I don't want my PC to work non-stop for that long. I want to say something like, 'Please stop rendering now and continue where you have left off later when I tell you to.'

Comment: Is suspending the process an option for you? Or perhaps, do several renders with fewer samples and different seeds and compose by hand?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Afaik this wasn't yet implemented, and the answers are either suspend process, or render image sequence if that's animation.